# If selection intersects with a named range then select that named range

Tags: excel, vba

My first plan was to repeat this for every named range, until i realized how much that would be.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("M_1")) Is Nothing Then
Else
    Range("M_1").Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just loop over the Named Ranges **in that sheet.**

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @Gary's Student Not that simple for me though

Comment: @JNevill @Scott @Gary added `On Error Resume Next` to scotts code and it worked perfectly Thank you all! Now, should I edit my code or do I leave it as it is ?

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want to change that `activecell` to `target` since `target` is static as the calling range. Also, just add a `NOT` condition to your `IF` so you don't have to use the `ELSE`

If you wanting to test `target` against a list of named ranges to see if `target` intersects at least one of the named ranges, you can use the application's `union` method:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("M_1"), Range("M_2"), Range("M_3")) Is Nothing Then
```

You could also do a loop if you need more control:

```
 doIntersect = false
 rngCounter = 0
 For each strTestRange in Array("M_1", "M_2", "M_3")
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range(strTestRange) Is Nothing Then
         doIntersect = true
         rngCounter = rngCounter + 1
     End if
 Next strTestRange

 If doIntersect Then
      msgbox(rngCounter & " named ranges intersect your selection")
 Else
      msgbox("None of the named ranges intersected your selection")
 End if
```

Comment: Not sure that I understand, I have 1260 named ranges, from M_1 to M_1260, how would you write that

Comment: See Scott's answer above. There he loops through every named range in the sheet. You can add a test inside that loop like `if left(nm.name, 2) = "M_" Then` if you have other named ranges. You could also set up a loop to go by the number: `For i = 1 to 1260`, `Range("M_" & i).DoSomething` There are a lot of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: It has been a while and I'm stuck, I think that I understand how his code works, correct me if I'm wrong but it runs a test over all named ranges to see if any of them intersects with the selected cell and selects the one named range that does. I don't believe that I need to run any additional tests within that since i will work with all named ranges, so I basically just copied his code and that left me with a runtime error that tells me the method 'Range' failed within the object '_Woorksheet' this has led me to learn a lot of other stuff but sadly not how to get this right

Comment: I would have asked scott if I had thought he would answer, there is maybe a simpel solution to this but I can't see it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add a loop to iterate through the named ranges:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim nm As Name
Dim nmStr As String
For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    nmStr = nm.Name
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(nmStr)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range(nmStr).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
Next nm

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't  know what I'm doing wrong but I can't get this to work