# Excel VBA - How to check if target is a named range. If yes, paste range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, named

I currently have my excel coded to do the following:

Whenever various specific text strings are typed anywhere in column B, a corresponding named range will be pasted at a relative offset.

Instead of typing each trigger term and corresponding named range in the code.....is there a way to instead have it dynamic?

IF target = "ANY named range"
THEN 
paste the named range

Here's snippet of current code. My eventual named range list will be growing, so this method is not going to be feasible when the named range list gets too big. It'll be a pain to maintain, hence my request here:

```
**Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Target = "Crew_Key_Non_Prompt" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Key_Non_Prompt").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Crew_Key_Prompt" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Key_Prompt").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Crew_Key_Target" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Key_Target").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Crew_Speed" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Speed").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Crew_Speed_Overspeed" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Speed_Overspeed").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Crew_Train_Orientation" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Train_Orientation").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Crew_Verbal_Confirmation" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Crew_Verbal_Confirmation").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Dispatcher_Action" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Dispatcher_Action_button").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Fence_Validation" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Fence_Validation").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Fence_Validation" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Fence_Validation").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Set_Device" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Set_Device").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Train_Switch_Navigation" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Train_Switch_Navigation").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Train_Target_Approach" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Train_Target_Approach").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Train_Target_Interaction" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Train_Target_Interaction").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf Target = "Train_Timed_Movement" Then
        Sheet1.Range("Train_Timed_Movement").Copy
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
     End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End Sub**
```

Comment: You could use `ThisWorkbook.Names` to loop through named ranges in your workbook. When you find one, perform your action and exit the loop

Comment: You could easily repurpose this, i think https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449283/2727437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the use of `On Error Resume Next` is generally discouraged, this could be an exception. If there is no named range on `Sheet1` corresponding to the value entered in `Target`, no copy/paste occurs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        On Error Resume Next
        Sheet1.Range(Target.Value).Copy Target.Offset(-1,1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: What happens if `Target.Value` is not a named range?

Comment: Nothing happens at all because of the `On Error Resume Next`. Which is 100% equivalent to what OP currently has - if there is no named range, nothing gets copied and pasted.

Comment: Good shout but you might want to reset it back to `On Error Goto 0`

Answer (score 1):

Some function like this is probably viable:

```
Public Function amInamedRange(myName As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo amInamedRange_Error

    If ws.Range(myName) <> "" Then
    End If
    amInamedRange = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

amInamedRange_Error:
    amInamedRange = False
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

And here is some possible usage:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If amInamedRange(Target.Value2, Target.Parent) Then
            Sheet1.Range(target).Copy
            Cells(Target.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced my code with yours and I get a Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch....

Comment: I think you are missing `ws` when calling `amInamedRange` UDF. Also, you are sending in a range when expecting a string

Comment: @Zac - yeah, this time the error description is 100% correct.

Comment: @user10429816 - give it a try again.

Comment: Plus1: much better than my approach of a loop through `ThisWorkbook.Names`

Comment: @Vitaya - where am I missing the ws? (sorry guys....newbie coder here...not actually a coder at all...)

Comment: @Zac - the `ThisWorkbook.Names` is more complicated, because if one of the names is defined with a `Worksheet` and not `Workbook` scope it will not be found as expected. E.g. if `someCrazyName` is defined with Worksheet scope in Sheet1, then if one loops through `ThisWorkbook.Names` it would show up as `Sheet1!somecrazyName` and this is not what is expected.

Comment: @Vityata: exactly right. I have fallen into that trap in the past

Comment: @viyata I used BigBen's code below. It did the trick. Thanks anyway everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

If the named ranges are single cells or formulas, then something like this would work:

```
Private Function getValueFromNamedRange(strName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Variant
    'Locally scoped names must include "<sheetName>!"
    Dim n As Name
    On Error GoTo uhoh
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each n In wb.Names
        If n.Name = strName Then getValueFromNamedRange = Evaluate(n.RefersTo): Exit Function
    Next
uhoh:
    getValueFromNamedRange = ""
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = getValueFromNamedRange("TEST")
    If s <> "" Then MsgBox s
End Sub
```